# An exception occurred when iOS 11 set prefersLargeTitles

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

Headline navigation bar effect, returns the animation is not smooth problem.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

I set the push page

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Detail"
    view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

[image]

System settings page, return animation is very smooth.
There is even a zoom animation, this should be the Apple API contains.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try setting your `viewWillDisappear` method when you quit your second view controller to this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

and then, in `viewWillAppear` you do this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

This will ensure a smooth transition over different styles

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried it, but the effect has not changed